# MATLAB optimization of the function

Tags: matlab, optimization

I want to optimize this function:

```
function Y_res = GetY( Y, P )
    cnt = length(P);
    denom = 0;
    for i = 1:cnt
        Y(i) = rand;
        denom = denom + P(i) / (1 - Y(i));
    end
    Y_res = 1 - 1 / denom;
    Y
    Y_res
end
```

This function receives Y and P. P is a constant array. I need to optimize Y array values. And I trying to do this:

```
Y = [0.3 0.2 0.1];     % need to be optimized
P = [0.65 0.2 0.15];   % constant array 

fhnd_GetY = @(x) GetY(Y, P);

options = optimset('TolX', 1e-3);
optimal_x = fminbnd(fhnd_GetY, 0.2, 0.4, options);
```

But the result of `optimal_x` variable does not equals to `Y_res`, which you can see on the screen during iterations of `GetY` function. Why? I need to optimze `Y_res` between 0.2 and 0.4 for example. So as a result I need to receive `Y_res` between 0.2 and 0.4 (for example) and `Y` array with values by means of which I can receive `Y_res`.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by "optimize Y array values". And the title reads - `optimization of the function`.

Comment: Did you realise that in the function `GetY(Y,P)`, you actually overwrite the value of `Y` with a random number?

Comment: So which function will generate Y values without generating random values?

Comment: Divakar, how I should call this subject?

Comment: I am not exactly sure about the terminologies used here - "optimize Y array", "constant array", "subject". Are you sure you are working with MATLAB?

Comment: @Gooman So, could you explain in a bit more detailed way on those three terms that you have used?

Comment: I need to receive Y_res in particular range, for example [0.2, 0.4]. In order to solve this problem I need to calculate (generate or optimize) Y array values. As you can see, function GetY calculates Y_res using Y and P arrays.

Comment: @Gooman So did the edits make solve it for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you only intend to optimize the function `GetY` and given the fact that you are creating `Y` inside it and as such don't need to externally input `Y` into it, see if this modified function is optimized enough for you -

```
function [Y_res,Y] = GetY( P )

found = false;
while ~found
    Y = rand(size(P));
    Y_res = 1-1./sum(P./(1-Y));

    if Y_res>0.2 & Y_res<0.4
        found = true;
    end
end

return;
```

Please note that if you don't need `Y` as an output, you can use `Yres = GetY([0.65 0.2 0.15])` instead, but most probably you would need that (my guess though).

Few sample runs -

```
>> [Yres,Y] = GetY([0.65 0.2 0.15])
Yres =
    0.3711
Y =
    0.4243    0.2703    0.1971
>> [Yres,Y] = GetY([0.65 0.2 0.15])
Yres =
    0.2723
Y =
    0.1897    0.4950    0.1476
>> [Yres,Y] = GetY([0.65 0.2 0.15])
Yres =
    0.3437
Y =
    0.3624    0.0495    0.4896
```